# Cannot assign to 'geolocation' because it is a read-only property (angular Jest)

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

[image][image][image: Not able to assign MockGeolocation return value.]

I'm trying to write test cases for AGM map and I found a blockage and was not able to resolve it by myself. Help would be much appreciated.
Refer the error message from the screenshot.

Comment: Please give a [mre] **as text**.

Comment: You've only added more screenshots...

Comment: The statement screenshots are clear to understand better than the words.

Comment: Screenshots are **not** _"better than the words"_.  They can't be indexed for searching, you can't copy-paste to actually run the code and (particularly in the absence of useful alt text) aren't accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  (window as any).navigator = mockNavigator;    
});

const mockNavigator = {
  geolocation: {
    getCurrentPosition: () => {},
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was just missing the type as any. 

note: beforeEach cannot be used in nested tests.

Answer (score 0):

**

> Jest is not able a read the type of geolocation. So, I just added the
> type as Any with the global variable. It worked perfectly for me.

**

```
 it('should get current location', async () => {

    const handleSpy = jest.spyOn(WhereToBuyComponent.prototype as any, 'setCurrentPosition');
    const mockGeolocation = {
      getCurrentPosition: jest.fn()
        .mockImplementationOnce((success) => Promise.resolve(success({
          coords: {
            latitude: 51.1,
            longitude: 45.3
          }
        })))
    };
    (global as any).navigator.geolocation = mockGeolocation;
    expect(handleSpy).toBeCalled;
  
});
```